# Java - strange task for overloading methods

Tags: java, casting

I have a task which should check if I understand overloading methods...

but this task confused me much more

What is an explanation of this fact?

```
    bar(i,c);
    bar(l,c);
```

Output:

```
II
DL
```

Is there any scheme how to solve such tasks, any rule?

```
public class Foo{

    static void bar(int a, double b){
    System.out.println("ID");
    }

    static void bar(int a, int b){
    System.out.println("II");
    }

    static void bar(double a, long b){
    System.out.println("DL");
    }

    static void bar(float... a){
    System.out.println("FS");
    }

    static void bar(int a, byte b){
    System.out.println("IB");
    }

    static void bar(double a, double b){
    System.out.println("DD");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int i=0;
        long l =0;
        float f=0;
        double d=0;
        char c='0';
        bar(i,f);
        bar(d,i);
        bar(i,c,i);
        bar(i,c);
        bar(l,c);

    }

}
```

Comment: What´s your exact question here or whats going wrong?

Comment: I think you should read more http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/

Comment: Since you are asking the question I suspect you didn't understand overloading yet. Read up on it, there are indeed rules for Java. For example look here: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/

Comment: What you're looking for is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Answer (score 1):

If there is a function that takes a `long` as a parameter and there is not one taking a `long`, and an `int` is supplied, then that `int` is *promoted* automatically to a `long` type.

If there is a function that takes a `double` as a parameter and there is not one taking a `double`, and a `long` is supplied, then that `long` is *promoted* automatically to a `double` type. Note that this conversion *can* cause you to lose precision: not all integers over the 53rd power of 2 can be represented exactly in a `double`.

These rules, of course, generalises to functions taking more than one parameter and explain the output your are observing.

Comment: It looks more like `c` is an `int` which is promoted to `long`.

Comment: Silly old cat. Amended to salvage some dignity.

Comment: Np ;) - Btw, I just saw `char c='0';` so it's `char`->`long`, oh and you were right: `l` is a `long` and is promoted to `double`, so `l`->`double`, `c`->`long`.

Comment: Your first version was already correct, you just omitted the widening of the second argument. Now you describe it for the second argument, but omitted it for the first one. Btw you can add the JLS link from my comment (under the question), it explains all possible primitive widening conversions.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> byte to short, int, long, float, or double
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> char to int, long, float, or double
>
> int to long, float, or double
>
> long to float or double
>
> float to double
>
> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value.

Basically since there's no long/char signature it will try to promote them to the above types and make decision based on that.
There's a fairly elaborate algorithm here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

And more specifically here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2